# Subprocess returns an empty string

Tags: python, bash

I would like to check the result of a Bash command in a Python script.
I'm using `subprocess.check_output()`.

Before that, I checked manually the result of two commands in a shell:

```
user@something:~$ hostname
> something

user@something:~$ command -v apt
> /usr/bin/apt
```

It works as expected. Now I'm trying to run the `subprocess.check_output()` function in the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['hostname'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
b'something\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output(['command', '-v', 'apt'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
b''
```

As you can see, the first command is working as expected, but not the second (as it returns an empty string). Why is that?

**EDIT**

I already tried removing `shell=True`, it returns an error:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['command', '-v', 'apt'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'command'
```

Comment: Removing `shell=True` will fix your issue. Also, you could use `shutil.which('apt')` instead of second call

Comment: why people set shell=True by default???

Comment: I didn't set `shell=True` by default, I added it because I was getting an error without it.

Comment: @Eldy that's easier to understand that way. `command` is built-in, so `shell=True` is necessary. But what does "command" do?

Comment: `echo $PATH` in terminal and with `subprocess.check_output(['echo', ' $PATH'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` will show you why. Also, to clarify - exec `which command` in terminal. I bet that it's location is not in $PATH using subprocess

Answer (score 0):

Drop `shell=True` from the parameters:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['command', '-v', 'apt'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
'/usr/bin/apt\n'
```

See [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess).

> If `shell` is `True`, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather
>   than as a sequence.

This ensures the command is properly formatted as it would if you had typed it directly in your shell:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output('command -v apt', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
'/usr/bin/apt\n'
```

However, using `shell` is generally discouraged.

Comment: can you explain why it's required?

Comment: I already tried that, and it's not working. I'll update my question.